# UTF-8 Encoding issue with HTTP Post object on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, linux, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I setting up a new server in AWS EBS with linux and configured the server to be UTF-8 because I use some text in Hebrew.

The code works on Windows but when I migrated to Linux this stopped working.
The code send HTTP post to another server and get JSON object from it and start to parse, All the Hebrew text is something like this: ×§×‘×•×¦×

1. I tried to add to AWS software configuration : JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS -Dfile.encoding=UTF8
2. I tried to add JAVA_OPTIONS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to tomcat8.conf file. (aslo tried with JAVA_OPTS).
3. I tried to add catalina options also with encoding.

   HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL);
           // Create JSON and set the API Token
           JSONObject SendJson = new JSONObject();
           SendJson.put(field,  key);
           StringEntity params =new StringEntity(SendJson.toString());
           request.setEntity(params);
           // set Header Type
           request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
           request.addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "UTF-8");
           // Execute and wait for response
           HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);

   ```
       HttpEntity resEntity =   httpResponse.getEntity();
       // cast InputStream to String for JSON conversion
       BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( resEntity.getContent()));
       //String strInputStream = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity,"UTF-8");
       String strInputStream = reader.readLine();

       //debug
       System.out.println("David Encoding problem");
       System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset().name());
       System.out.println(strInputStream);
       JSONObject answerObj = new JSONObject(strInputStream);
   ```

Charset.defaultCharset().name() - output UTF-8

I get JSON with no Hebrew text :/

part of the JSON for example:
{"item_group_id":1,"item_group_name":"×§×‘×•×¦×” ×","picture_link":""},

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
I changed the locale to he_IL and he_IL.UTF8, then restarted the server and it worked.

Thanks!